# Sum calculation of measured column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I am using power-bi-desktop (May 2022) in combination with report-server.

I have a table with lot numbers and a calculated columns count and dist.
The table is filtered by a slicer and aggregated (mean multiple lines are shown as one row in the visual.
Additionally the rows which have to be shown in the visual are indicated by the measure __visible = 1.
Within that set the row with the measue LOI = 1 have to be excluded from calculation.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKr8D.png)

Now I wanna add a new measue which shows the sum of column dist and average of count over all shown entries.

The sum of dist is 9.2

I already tried:

```
sumx(groupby(allselected(Complaints), Complaints[Index]), Complaints[DIST])
==> takes infinity time

sumx(ADDCOLUMNS(allselected(Complaints), "test", [DIST]), [test])
==> calculates 8.48

sumx(ADDCOLUMNS(filter(allselected(Complaints), Complaints[LOI] <> 1 && Complaints[__visible] = 1), "test", [DIST]), [test])
==> calculates 10

SUMX(Filter(allselected(Complaints), Complaints[LOI] <> 1 && Complaints[__visible] = 1), Complaints[DIST])
==> calculates 10

SUMX(Allselected(Complaints), Complaints[DIST])
==> calculates 8.48

SUMMARIZE(Filter(allselected(Complaints), Complaints[LOI] <> 1 && Complaints[__visible] = 1),Complaints[Index], "jj", Complaints[DIST])
sumx(tt, [jj])
==> calculates 10

SUMMARIZE(allselected(Complaints), Complaints[Index], "jj", Complaints[DIST]) 
sumx(tt, [jj])
==> calculates 8.48
```

Any ideas how I can calculate the correct sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUMX` and iterate over `VALUES`. Use `CALCULATE` to force context transition:

```
Sum of Dist =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( 'Complaints'[Index] ),
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Complaints'[DIST] ) )
)
```

Comment: Hi,
as [DIST] is a measure and for performance I added a filter to the value function: sumx(Filter(values(ComplaintLots[Index]), Complaints[__visible]=1), CALCULATE(sumx(Allselected(Complaints), Complaints[DIST]))).
But the result is with 8.48 still wrong :-(((